# Similar code of take()&groupBy() applied to timer() resulting in different results

Tags: rx-java

The following two pieces of code from learnrxjava repo (https://github.com/jhusain/learnrxjava) yield different results:

```
Observable.timer(0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .groupBy(n -> n % 2 == 0)
                .flatMap(g -> {
                    return g.take(10).toList();
                }).take(2).toBlocking().forEach(System.out::println);
```

and

```
Observable.timer(0, 1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .take(20)
                .groupBy(n -> n % 2 == 0)
                .flatMap(g -> {
                    return g.toList();
                })
                .toBlocking()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

yields

```
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
```

and

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

respectively. I just couldn't figure out why the result is flipped in the second case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is the inner `take` forcing the signaling of the even group before the groupBy would complete.

GroupBy holds two groups in a map, which have a natural order for *false (odd group)* and *true (even group)*.

When the source emits 18, the *true (even) group* gets all its 10 items and `take` issues an `onCompleted`, finishing the list which then gets emitted by `flatMap`. Next, the source emits 19 which completes the *false (odd) group* and does the same.

When there is no inner `take`, both groups stay active until the source completes after 20 items. Upon completion, the `groupBy` notifies the *false (odd) group* first about completion, which then emits the odd list first, then the *true (even) group* is completed, emitting the even list.